# Why Azure VM have DVD Drive?

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2

What is the use of DVD Drive in an Azure VM? I do not see it in AWS VM. Is it safe to change its default drive letter from `E` to `Z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might have something to do with how they are provisioned, for example scvmm attaches small iso file to a VM when it creates a VM from template (to inject scvmm agent).
I'm pretty sure its 101% safe to change drive letter of the dvd drive.